# Optimizing the query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with two kinds of sources in the source column, one external and another one internal.My requirement is to find out the same record between external and internal based on COLUMNA and COLUMNB. If the internal and external record matches for COLUMNA, I need to take the corresponding ID(ID column value will be always unique) from both internal and external.I have millions of record in my table.And there will be duplicates records in each sources. I have given the query which is written(I use UNION ALL to improve the performance,even though duplicate ID will come in the final output), but it is taking 2 hours.So is there anyway I can rewrite this query, I am using DB2 here.

For example if below is my input record.

[image]

```
ID  COLUMNA COLUMNB  SOURCE

1   DELL    Finland  INTERNAL

2   CTS     USA      INTERNAL

3   CTS     AUST     INTERNAL

4   TCS     FIN      INTERNAL

5   CTS     SING     INTERNAL

6   IBM     NEWZ     EXTERNAL

7   CTS     AUST     EXTERNAL

8   TCS     Finland  EXTERNAL

9   TCS     Finland  EXTERNAL
```

Expected output

[image]

The query which is already written is given below.

```
select  ID from TABLE where COLUMNA in(
(select SRC.COLUMNA from TABLE SRC,TABLE REF  
where SRC.SOURCE<>'EXTERNAL' and REF.SOURCE='EXTERNAL' and SRC.COLUMNA=REF.COLUMNA))
UNION ALL
select  ID from TABLE where COLUMNB in(
(select SRC.COLUMNB from TABLE SRC,TABLE REF  
where SRC.SOURCE<>'EXTERNAL' and REF.SOURCE='EXTERNAL' and 
SRC.COLUMNB=REF.COLUMNB))
```

Comment: Is your expect output correct? By my understanding of your requriment, you would want just ID's 3 and 7 returned

Comment: Yes my expected output is correct. I need ID from both the sources and also based on both the columns.Even though ID 1 dosent match for COLUMNA, it matches with COLUMNB for the value Finland. SOrry if the requirement I wrote is not clear. But I hope you got my requirement from the query which I wrote

Comment: You should post your data as text not a picture..

Comment: I am trying to paste it as text. But its not getting formatted correctly.

Comment: Use fixed width formatting but indenting each line with 4 spaces, or press Ctrl-K or press the `{ }` code sample button. Ideally show data as a VALUES clause as used in my answer

Comment: BTW if you need still performance help even after the suggested query alternatives, you should probably post your DDL, an explain plan and key system details such as SORTHEAP size... but do that in a new Q if you do

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `id`s where either column is repeated in the two sides.

For that, you can use window functions:

```
select distinct t.id
from (select t.*,
             min(source) over (partition by column_a) as min_a,
             max(source) over (partition by column_a) as max_a,
             min(source) over (partition by column_b) as min_b,
             max(source) over (partition by column_b) as max_b
      from t
     ) t
where min_a <> max_a or min_b <> max_b;
```

This assumes only the two sources you have in the question.  If there are others, then add a `where` clause in the subquery to filter only for those two.

Comment: yea actually there are multiple internal sources, which I call it as internal all together. Again sorry for this

Comment: There is a typo in the query text: you use `min` function for the `max_x` columns :)

Comment: The query works after I update all the other sources to Internal.But its slower than my original query :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT ID
    , SUM(SOURCE = 'INTERNAL') OVER(PARTITION BY CA) AS INT_A
    , SUM(SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL') OVER(PARTITION BY CA) AS EXT_A
    , SUM(SOURCE = 'INTERNAL') OVER(PARTITION BY CB) AS INT_B
    , SUM(SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL') OVER(PARTITION BY CB) AS EXT_B
    FROM 
        T
) WHERE (INT_A > 0 AND EXT_A) > 0 OR (INT_B > 0 AND EXT_B) > 0
ORDER BY ID
```

which returns

```
ID
--
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 7
 8
 9
```

Comment: I tried the above query but its giving me error like "missing right parenthesis", also I did some modification sum(source<>'EXTERNAL'), as I have multiple internal sources, which call altogether as  INTERNAL in my requirement

Comment: The `SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL'` bit in the above SQL will only work on DB2 11.1.1.0 and above, as it they have support for BOOLEAN datatype. In earlier versions use e.g. `CASE WHEN SOURCE = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID
--, COLUMNA_SOURCE_DISTINCT, COLUMNB_SOURCE_DISTINCT
FROM
(
SELECT 
  T.*
-- COUNT DISTINCT OLAP specification is not supported; we emulate it below
-- COUNT(DISTINCT SOURCE) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMNA) COLUMNA_SOURCE_DISTINCT 
, COUNT(NULLIF(SOURCE, LAG(SOURCE) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMNA ORDER BY SOURCE))) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMNA) COLUMNA_SOURCE_DISTINCT 
, COUNT(NULLIF(SOURCE, LAG(SOURCE) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMNB ORDER BY SOURCE))) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMNB) COLUMNB_SOURCE_DISTINCT 
FROM TABLE T
)
WHERE COLUMNA_SOURCE_DISTINCT + COLUMNB_SOURCE_DISTINCT <> 2;
```

## Alternative solution without OLAP functions

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM TABLE B
WHERE B.COLUMNA=A.COLUMNA 
AND 
   CASE A.SOURCE WHEN 'EXTERNAL' THEN 'EXTERNAL' ELSE 'INTERNAL' END
<> CASE B.SOURCE WHEN 'EXTERNAL' THEN 'EXTERNAL' ELSE 'INTERNAL' END
)

  UNION

SELECT ID
FROM TABLE A
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM TABLE B
WHERE B.COLUMNB=A.COLUMNB 
AND 
   CASE A.SOURCE WHEN 'EXTERNAL' THEN 'EXTERNAL' ELSE 'INTERNAL' END
<> CASE B.SOURCE WHEN 'EXTERNAL' THEN 'EXTERNAL' ELSE 'INTERNAL' END
);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this query also.. From an intial run I can see it is taking lot of time to fetch record